# How to query for a dictionary in Mongo Document?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Document, shown below

This is my C# structure for that document

```
public class MetaData
{
  [BsonId]
  public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("User")]
  public IDictionary<Int64, FirstUser> User { get; set; }
}

public class FirstUser
{
    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Id")]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is my BSON structure for that document

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5805c1ced520b54bd4192214"),
    "User" : [ 
        [ 
            NumberLong(1), 
            {
                "Name" : "FirstUser",
                "_id" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        ]
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5805c1ced520b54bd4192215"),
    "User" : [ 
        [ 
            NumberLong(1), 
            {
                "Name" : "SecondUser",
                "_id" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        ]
    ]
}


/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5805c1ced520b54bd4192216"),
    "User" : [ 
        [ 
            NumberLong(1), 
            {
                "Name" : "ThirdUser",
                "_id" : NumberLong(3)
            }
        ]
    ]
}


/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5805c1ced520b54bd4192217"),
    "User" : [ 
        [ 
            NumberLong(1), 
            {
                "Name" : "FourthUser",
                "_id" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I need all documents which are having "Name" as "FirstUser", For this how do I form MONGO QUERY?

Comment: Your BSON schema and your classes do not seem to match... your BSON seems to have "User" as array of object array instead of just the dictionary.

Comment: Can i propose you to use Aggregation Framework to resolve it? If yes, i can write you an answer.

Comment: I already tired that it was working, But the problem here is I am not able to fetch more than 16 MB. Some times i have to fetch more than 16 MB.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your dictionary keys are numbers. Usually you'd use something like `"User.1.Name": "FirstUser"`, but this syntax actually does something else: looking for the second element in `User` which has `Name=FirstUser` (because the indexing is zero-based).

If you have only one key in `User`, you can use `"User.0.Name": "FirstUser"`.

Comment: This works, But problem here is user can be any where we can't tell that it always come first in dictionary.

Comment: Can you give an example for your schema when it's the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from the mongo shell using the following:

```
db.collection.find({'User.Name': 'FirstUser'});
```

Or from the c# driver you can do the following:

```
var c = await wat.FindAsync(x => x.User[0].Name == "FirstUser");
var metaData = await c.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: actually i need mongo query, Because first i make query then i try to take the document. How to make make for that

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is on example that works for me:

`var query = new Dictionary<string, object>()`
            {
                { "$match", new { id = 11 }}
             };`

 
var result = services.Query<objectType>(query);
```